# How to make a nested JSON from a form in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to make a nested JSON, taking the values from a form. I have 2 interfaces

```js
export Interface User{
username:string;
name:string;
passwordField:Password;
}

export Interface Password{
password:string;
secretQuestion:string;
}
```

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label> <B>FORM TITLE</B></label>
  <hr>
    <label for="USER NAME">USER NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="user.username" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
<label for="NAME"> NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="user.name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PASSWORD">PASSWORD:</label>
    <input type="password" required [(ngModel)]="User.passwordField.password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="SECRET QUESTION">SECRET QUESTION:</label>
    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="User.passwordField.secretQuestion" class="form-control" id="secretQuestion" name="secretQuestion">
  </div>
  <button type="submit"[disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
onSubmit(user:User){
 alert(JSON.stringify(user))
 }
```

but here in the alert I get {}, where as passing values to form as

```
<label for="NAME"> NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
```

makes a simple JSON. can we only convert a form obj to a obj of a class and not dirctely of type Interface??

Comment: You can use [reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), this link has similar examples you need.

Comment: @LeonardoOliveira Thank you so much...that was very helpful.